# (Operator) norm inequality for continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $f,g$ be two non-negative continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying $f(t)g(t)=t,$ $\forall t\in[0,\infty)$. Let be $A$ be a bounded linear operator acting on a Hilbert space. Then I was wondering if the following inequality is always true:

$$\|f(|A|)\|\; \|g(|A^*|)\|\geq \|A\|.$$

Comment: $f(|A|)$ is a non-negative real number. Why do you put it between $\|\cdot\|$? Perhaps you mean $f(\|A\|)$?

Comment: No, I think it is $f(|A|)$....

Comment: @ajotatxe: I would guess that $|A|$ is the absolute value of $A$ in the polar decomposition $A =V \cdot |A|$, where $V$ is a partial isometry. Then $f(|A|)$ refers to the usual functional calculus for self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that $|A|, |A^\ast|$ are positive semi-definite, self-adjoint operators which both have operator norm $\Vert A \Vert$.

Hence, $\sigma(|A|) \cup \sigma(|A^\ast|) \subset [0, \Vert A \Vert]$. Since the operator norm equals the spectral-radius for self-adjoint operators, we get $\Vert A \Vert \in \sigma(|A|) \cap \sigma(|A^\ast|)$.

Now, since $f,g$ are continuous, elementary properties of the spectral calculus (the Gelfand transform is an isometry on the continuous functions on the spectrum) yield

$$
\Vert f(|A|) \Vert = \sup_{x \in \sigma(|A|)} |f(x)| \geq |f(\Vert A \Vert)|.
$$

Analogously,
$$
\Vert g(|A^\ast|) \Vert = \sup_{x \in \sigma(|A^\ast|)} |g(x)| \geq |g(\Vert A \Vert)|.
$$

All in all, we get

$$
\Vert f(|A|) \Vert \cdot \Vert g(|A^\ast|) \Vert \geq |f(\Vert A \Vert)| \cdot |g(\Vert A \Vert)| = \Vert A \Vert,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Looks okay. I will accept it, once I check this Gelfand transform (I did not know about it). Thanks.